# linux cat command executed via phpseclib exec function returns empty result

Tags: php, cat, phpseclib

i'm using phpseclib's Net_SSH2 class to execute a number of commands on a remote server. I need to retrieve the content of a certain XML file from the server. Problem is when i run a linux cat cmd like so:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($host, $port);
if($ssh->connect($username, $password)){

  $script = "cat '$xml_file'"; 
  $output = $ssh->exec($script);
}else{
  exit('Login Failed');
}
```

the $output is an empty array. I double checked it by running the $script command on the server itself via putty and here the contents of the xml file is returned. Is this an implementation issue with phpseclib that prevents it from returning the proper output?

Comment: Are you sure `$ssh->exec()` returns the output and not some kind of resource? At least [ssh2_exec](http://php.net/ssh2_exec) does so.

Comment: did a var_dump and it returns: array(0) { }

Comment: Is the connection successfully created? Try `if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) exit('Login Failed');`

Comment: tried, and got the same result

Comment: are you sure about the path of the xml file? try to use absolute path to the xml file

Comment: yes, when i var_dump the contents of $script and use putty to execute it, it works.

Comment: Are you suing the latest SVN version of Net_SSH2?  Looking at the phpseclib SVN myself I'm not even sure how $ssh->exec() could return an array.  Looks like it either returns a boolean or a string.